# Как поставить условие?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет. Делаю вот бесконечную прокрутку(ajax прокрутку) на vue. Запрос к серверу сделал, а вот поставить условие, чтоб этот скрипт срабатывал когда пользователь прокручивал scroll на 1000px от низа страницы не могу... Помогите, как это условие составить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, что изначальная высота документа с отступами и невидимым контентом - `1000`(px), `scrollY` - число пикселей, на которое в данный момент документ пролистали, `innerHeight` - начальная высота окна без отступов (значение не меняется):

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            list: [],
            onScroll: () => {
                const { scrollHeight } = document.documentElement;
                const { scrollY, innerHeight } = window;

                if (scrollY + innerHeight !== scrollHeight) {
                    return;
                }

                axios.get('/api/some-endpoint').then((res) => {
                    this.$data.list.push(res.data);
                });
            }
        };
    },

    created() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.$data.onScroll);
    },

    beforeDestroy() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.$data.onScroll);
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Очень даже помогло, но вот зачем вы в data описываете метод?) есть же для этого объект methods

Comment: вы можете объявлять методы где угодно, поведение компонента от этого не изменится, в `methods` вы определяете функции для обработки `DOM` событий (`@click | @submit` etc...), функции которые вы используете только внутри компонента - вы можете объявлять в `data`, опять же - делайте как вам удобно

Comment: Понятно, спасибо еще раз:)

Comment: $data  было нормально использовать в vue 0.x, в 2.x должно нормально работать без него. А методы все же лучше использовать в методах я думаю. Также `onScroll: () => {` можно тоже писать в коротком виде `onScroll () {`

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, нет, нельзя в коротком виде, читайте про замыкание и куда будет указывать `this`

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, не знаю откуда вы берете все эту информацию, есть `vue best practices` отточенные командой `vue` уже несколько лет. К тому же если вы делаете "замечание" по поводу того, как лучше писать код - воспроизведите этот пример сначала у себя и посмотрите как поведет себя программа

Comment: Перечитаю про $data, просто редко встречаю такое, ну и работает без $data норм, нашел я эту инфу вот где: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176073/what-is-vue-way-to-access-to-data-from-methods#comment83165991_36176190

Comment: Я создал код посмотрите, там в mounted можно получить значение из объекта, а в data если метод, то он будет ссылаться на window почему-то  https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/PBEGQy?editors=1010

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, как говорил классик - учиться, учиться и еще раз учиться :-)

Comment: в смысле Вы все же не правы и вам надо подучить или я затупил?) Вот переделал чуть код в mounted, какрзтаки стрелочная функция не должна получать свойства объекта https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/PBEGQy?editors=1010

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, что вы от меня хотите услышать? я вам сказал читать про замыкание контекста `this` и в чем разница между обычной и лямбдой, к тому же когда вы сказали, что `this` указывает на `window` - вы уже ответили на свой вопрос. Cheers

Comment: Я не могу понять почему если в data написать обычную ф-ю то ее this будет не объект в котором она создана а window(это в случае если однофайловый компонент) Если через обычный new Vue то там не важно стрелочная или обычная ф-я: значение из data достается. Вот ссылка где я показал что в первых двух примерах обыная ф-я достает значение из data, а стрелочная нет, а в последнем примере то что я писал про new Vue. https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/PBEGQy?editors=1010

Comment: То есть vue меняет контекст this, например, вот если есть методы в methods: { a () { retrun this.var } } если вызвать a то по обычной логике js будет искаться a в объекте methods, но не в data! vue для удобства меняет контекст. Так что я вроде понимаю как работает this, vue отдельный это случай.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, вы не понимаете, vue ничего не меняет) https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-javascripts-this-keyword/ читаем до посинения

Comment: Спасибо большое за статью, забыл что если передавать метод то он теряет свой контекст. Сейчас просто нагрузил себя js + php технологиями всякими, забываются такие моменты, но ниче, с годами такие моменты закрепятся. Поправь эту мысль, пожалуйста, если не прав: ко всем ф-ям компонента vue(data, created, mounted и т.д) биндится this компонента в котором проксятся свойства объектов data(который возвращается) , methods, computed.  Поэтому this в стрелочной ф-ии которая в data ссылается на компонент, она берет this из метода data(this data === this стрелочной ф-ии)